# How to do a "distinct" (unique) query in the Solr 8 web interface?

Tags: search, solr, unique, distinct, solr8

We use a **Solr 8.11.2** server. Also we use the Solr 8 web user interface to query the Solr cores.

How can I make a **"distinct"** (unique) query using this interface? In my example I want to know how many different values for the field **"site"** there are.

[image]

I read I can use the **"Facet"** option. But I only found very old posts (for Solr 4 and Solr 5), and nothing I read worked.

Can someone tell me what to input to get the distinct values for the field **"site"** (or any other field)?

Thanks

Comment: you can try below query http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=*%3A*&rows=0&facet=on&facet.field=site  OR /select?stats=on&stats.field=site&rows=0&stats.calcdistinct=true

Comment: Thanks, but this does not work. It produces an error. See post for details.

Comment: I had given 2 alternatives not one.... the first one you can try is  localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=*%3A*&rows=0&facet=on&facet.field=site

Comment: The second one you can try is localhost:8983/solr/select?stats=on&stats.field=site&rows=0&stats.calcdistinct=true..

Comment: (and to add the explanation: faceting gives you all the unique values for a field and their counts, which you've probably seen as navigators as most ecommerce websites (or search engines) where you're allowed to filter/narrow your results by selecting a color/size/etc. - the value in a specific field across all documents).

Comment: Thanks @AbhijitBashetti. Now I get it. The first alternative works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The faceting option would work in this case. You can try below query

```
localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=*%3A*&rows=0&facet=on&facet.field=site
```

> Faceting is the arrangement of search results into categories based on
> indexed terms.
>
> Searchers are presented with the indexed terms, along with numerical
> counts of how many matching documents were found were each term.
> Faceting makes it easy for users to explore search results, narrowing
> in on exactly the results they are looking for

More on faceting can be found on the solr page [solr faceting](https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/faceting.html#:%7E:text=Faceting%20is%20the%20arrangement%20of,were%20found%20were%20each%20term.)

Comment: I was missing the setting the **rows** to **0**. Great. Now it works. Thanks